# Discrete Fourier transform for periodic signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, discrete, signal-processing

From the Signal and System textbook, by Oppenheim, I learned that the discrete-time Fourier transform can be written as

$$
x[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{2\pi}X(e^{j\omega})e^{j\omega n}d\omega
$$
$$
X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n]e^{-j\omega n}
$$

From page 364, sec 5.1.

Now,next section, The Fourier Transform for periodic signals, considering the signal
$$
x[n]=e^{j\omega_0 n}
$$
in the textbook, the Fourier transform of this signal is
$$
X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{l=-\infty}^{+\infty} 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0-2\pi l)
$$

I know this makes sense in non-mathematical way, but from the definition of discrete-time Fourier transform, I couldn't derive this formula.
$$
X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n]e^{-j\omega n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j\omega_0 n}e^{-j\omega n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j(\omega_0 -\omega)n}
$$
The last term, I believe, does not converge....

where did that $2\pi l$ come from in the "pure" mathematics?

Comment: OP's question (v2) is essentially asking why the Fourier coefficients are 1 for the Fourier series for the [Dirac comb/Shah distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb). Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The name of the thing you need to learn is the "Poisson summation formula". I wrote out a derivation to it on [a Math.SE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242280/what-is-the-sum-over-a-shifted-sinc-function/1242281#1242281). That final sum doesn't converge in the usual sense. It turns out to be equal to an infinite sum of delta functions.

Comment: Ah!!!! it can be represented as Fourier series! wow!!!